# Cannot control size of twitter search result from C#, twitter REST API

Tags: c#, api, rest, search, twitter

I am using C# for collecting tweets by REST API.
Search API has count parameter to control size of result.

I don't know why this parameter does not work when it is over 15.

When the value of count is under 15, it works fine.(3, 5, and so on.)
If it is over 15, it still show only 15 tweets.

var timelineUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=test&count=17";

This is my code.

```
        var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

        var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString("") + ":" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString(("")))
        ));
        var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";

        HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        authRequest.Method = "POST";
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        using (System.IO.Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
        // deserialize into an object
        TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse;
        using (authResponse)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objectText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                twitAuthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitAuthenticateResponse>(objectText);
            }
        }

        // Do the timeline
        var timelineFormat = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={0}&include_rts=1&exclude_replies=1&count=5";
        //var timelineUrl = string.Format(timelineFormat, "shj860728");
        var timelineUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=test&count=17";
        HttpWebRequest timeLineRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(timelineUrl);
        var timelineHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
        timeLineRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format(timelineHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type, twitAuthResponse.access_token));
        timeLineRequest.Method = "Get";
        WebResponse timeLineResponse = timeLineRequest.GetResponse();
        var timeLineJson = string.Empty;
        using (timeLineResponse)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(timeLineResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                timeLineJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        //foreach(var tweet : )

        JObject result = JObject.Parse(timeLineJson);
        IList<JToken> results = result["statuses"].Children().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from below.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/problem-bug-get-search-tweets-count-parameter/10249/10

When I add result_type parameter, it works.

"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=test&result_type=recent&count=30"